# How to make the animation of changing colors in animate.css

Tags: animation, animate.css

I was watching the animate.css web page, I want to make the color changing animation that they applied in the animate.css title of their main page, how can I do that?

https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/

Answer (score 2):

Try it out

```css
h1 {
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -webkit-animation: colored 10s infinite linear;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, #f35626, #feab3a);
}
@-webkit-keyframes colored {
  from {
    -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(-360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Colored text</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use web inspector to find out (right click and select inspect element).

They have an h1 with the following style definitions:

```
h1.site__title {
    color: #f35626;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(92deg, #f35626, #feab3a);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;.
    -webkit-animation: hue 60s infinite linear;
}

@-webkit-keyframes hue {
  from {
    -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(0deg);
  }

  to {
    -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(-360deg);
  }
}
```